# How can I add link to my image on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use `link_to` syntax on this line but nothing working out.
How can I do that in ruby on rails?

```
<%= image_tag post.picture.url if post.picture? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`link_to`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) `do` block

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  <%= image_tag post.picture.url if post.picture? %>
<%= end %>
```

Comment: thnx a lot for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<% if post.picture? %>
  <%= link_to "/path" do %>
    <%= image_tag post.picture.url %>
  <%= end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thnx a lot for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
<%= link_to image_tag post.picture.url, navigate_to_path if post.picture? %>
```

OR

You can also try below if you need a block for additional things along with an image.

```
<%= link_to navigate_to_path do %>
  <%= image_tag post.picture.url %>
<% end if post.picture? %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thnx a lot for ur help

Comment: You can flag it accepted, so other  can find it useful @Shofi